# Wie lauten die Einwohnerbezeichnungen (Demonyme) von Orten mit bestimmtem Artikel?

Tags: proper-noun

Es gibt Orte mit bestimmten Artikeln und attributiven Adjektiven, z.B. le Havre, le Locle, den Haag, la Chaux-de-Fonds, Buenos Aires usw. Es ist mir schwierig die richtigen Demonyme für die Einwohner von diesen Orten zu bilden. New-Yorker (oder Newyorker?) wäre ja für New York richtig, aber ein Muster daraus zu machen ist nicht selbstverständlich.
Le-Havreianer, Lelocler, Den-Haagier, La-Chauxdefondsiten, Buenos-Air(es)ier?

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass eis ein allgemeingültiges Muster dafür gibt.

Comment: Jedenfalls gibt es keine Bindestriche oder Zusammenschreibung ^^

Comment: Bei solch komplizierten Namen wird gern *die Einwohner von …* verwendet.

Comment: München/Münchner, Paris/Pariser, Prag/Prager, den Haag/den Haager - wieso _den Haagier_? (Habgier? :) ) Oder Buenos Airesier, wieso das i?

Comment: Wenn du schon in GSE fragst, dann frag' doch auch gleich nach "Bad Salzdetfurth", "Bad Gottleuba-Berggießhübel", "Baden-Baden" und "Karl-Marx-Stadt". Oder, um's richtig kompliziert zu machen "Gabe Gottes" (bei Probstzella) oder in Österreich besonders schön "Kirchschlag in der Buckligen Welt"

Comment: @Janka. das wäre wohl dann eine Antwort?

Comment: Es heißt _Haager Landkriegsordnung_ (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haager_Landkriegsordnung), also wird zumindest im Fall von Den Haag der Artikel anscheinend weggelassen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Für solche Namen gibt es meist keine etablierten Einwohnerbezeichnungen. Üblicherweise sagt man tatsächlich "Einwohner von ..." (bzw. Bewohner, Bürger etc.).

Hier meine Meinung ohne großartige Recherche:

- **Den Haag:** *Den-Haager* erscheint mir mit gewissem Unbehagen akzeptabel - und es findet sich auch so als Adjektiv gebraucht.
- **Le Havre:** Falls ich gefragt würde und ich nicht "Gibts nicht!" antworten darf: *Le-Havrais* oder *Le-Havrer*.
- **Le Locle**: Am ehesten *Loclois(er)*, vielleicht sagen Deutschschweizer aber auch *Lokler*.
- **Buenos Aires:** *Buenairenser*, wenn unvermeidbar.

Comment: Man sagt aber z.B. "Haager Landkriegsordnung" und nicht "den-Haager Landkriegsordung"

Comment: Also auf Spanisch ist auch *Bonaerense* (lit. Gutluftiger) nicht einfach zu erraten.

Comment: @c.p.: Richtig, das Buenairenser orientiert sich am Spanischen (genauso wie sich Le-Havrais oder Locloiser am Französischen orientiert).

Comment: Die Einwohner von Buenos Aires nennt man Porteños.

Comment: @tofro: Richtig, aber vor allem innerhalb von Argentinien (und Cono Sur). Anderswo würde man zunächst an [andere Orte](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porteño_(gentilicio)) denken. Vielleicht findet man das Wort in deutschen Reiseführern.